# Will initializing a variable in its declaration make it recreate every time its called?

Tags: java

I usually avoid doing this, but I stumble upon this from time to time in some code examples, and I'd like to know.

For example you have this:

```
private Object obj;

public void someMethod() {
   obj = new Object();
}
```

And thus the object will be initialized only when `someMethod()` is called.

But what if the variable is declared like this:

```
private Object obj = new Object();
```

later when I use the `obj` variable somewhere, will that kind of declaration make it create a new instance every time its being referenced?

Comment: use constructor instead

Comment: I believe that way the variable will be initialized automatically when the constructor is called.

Comment: lets say there is no constructor in that class

Comment: @Borislav so, you are calling the constructor of a class that doesn't have a Constructor? In Java, it is not possible to have a class that does not have a constructor. All you can do is set the access modifier to private.

Comment: use instance block than as many times you instantiate class the instance block will be executed @Borislav

Comment: Then there is the default constructor

Comment: I am talking about classes like Android's Activity, which have no explicit constructors

Comment: then call the default one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a field has an initialization statement, it will be initialized with the value of that statement exactly once, when the instance is created. In other words, when you instantiate a class, its instance field initializers and initializers blocks are run, and then the constructor body is executed.

Accessing a field does not trigger its field initialization statement (if it event has one)  again.

Answer (score 0):

You create a new instance using (surprise) the 'new' keyword. 'new Object()' will call the constructor for Object() and return the new instance of Object. This is true for all (non abstract) classes, even those without explicit constructors, as every class has a default constructor.

Comment: so it will be initialized only in the declaration ONCE, and not later, when only being referenced somewhere in the code?

Comment: @Borislav the declaration, 'private Object obj', does not create an instance. It simply declares a variable, 'obj', that is ready to hold a reference to an object of type 'Object'. The instance is only created once you 'instantiate' an object with the 'new' keyword and assign it to your reference variable. You are then free to use your variable to manipulate the object.

Comment: I still dont understand how many time an instance of 'obj' will be created when executing this line - "private Object obj = new Object();"

Comment: @Borislav 'private Object obj' declares a variable.  

'= new Object()' instantiates a new instance of Object() and assigns it to 'obj'.

One instance is created. Using the variable 'obj' will now reference that object. Using 'obj' does not create a new object every time you use it, it references the one object you assigned to it when you called 'new Object()'. calling 'Object obj = new Object() has the EXACT same outcome as separating them like you did in your original post.